# why is a function with async modifier throwing error on await call

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, module

I have a node+ express application where a controller method is performing asynchronous operation. Even though the method is declared with `async` modifier it throws `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`.

The routes are set-up like :

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

//create  and  import controllers
var todoCtr = require("../controllers/todos");

router.get("/todos", todoCtr.listTodos);
router.post("/todos", todoCtr.createTodo);
router.put("/todos/:todoId", todoCtr.updateTodo);

module.exports = router;
```

My todo controller folder is structured where each method has its own file and are then exported as a whole in `index.js` file.

The index.js file:
`index.js`

```
const createTodo = require("./createTodo");
const listTodos = require("./listTodos");
const updateTodo = require("./updateTodo");

module.exports = {
  listTodos,
  createTodo,
  updateTodo,
};
```

The update method looks like:
`updateTodo.js`

```
const Todo = require("../../models").Todo;
const Subtask = require("../../models").Subtask;
const { isStatusChangeCorrect } = require("./helpers/updateTodoHelpers");
const { Op } = require("sequelize");

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  //find the todo needed to be updated
  return Todo.findByPk(req.params.todoId)
    .then((todo) => {
      if (!todo) {
        return res.status(404).send({
          message: "Todo Not Found",
        });
      }
       const  answerr = await isStatusChangeCorrect(todo.status, req.body.status, req.params.todoId);

      console.log("aaa2", subtaskMarkedCompleted);
      console.log("aaa", totalSubtasks);
      return todo
        .update({
          status: req.body.status || todo.status,
        })
        .then(() => res.status(200).send(todo))
        .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
    })
    .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
};
```

Here I'm trying to use await for a function(`isStatusChangeCorrect`) that will perform a db/asynchorous operation but I get an error message with trace stack :

```
/Users/haroonAzhar/Desktop/test/OOZOU-TEST/server/controllers/todos/updateTodo.js:15
       const  answerr = await isStatusChangeCorrect(todo.status, req.body.status, req.params.todoId);
                        ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/haroonAzhar/Desktop/test/OOZOU-TEST/server/controllers/todos/index.js:3:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
```

Why am I getting synax error when the function is declared with `async modifier`?

The helper isn't finished yet but looks somehing like this : `todoHelpers/updateTodoHelper.js`

```
const Todo = require("../../models").Todo;
const Subtask = require("../../models").Subtask;
const isStatusChangeCorrect = async (currrentStatus, statusToSet, todoId) => {
  let totalSubtasks;
  let subtaskMarkedCompleted;
  const countPromise = Subtask.findAndCountAll({
    where: {
      parentId: req.params.todoId,
    },
  });
  // .then((result) => {
  //   totalSubtasks = result.count;
  //   console.log("ez  ccount 1", result.count);
  // });
  const countPromise2 = Subtask.findAndCountAll({
    where: {
      [Op.and]: [{ parentId: req.params.todoId }, { status: "completed" }],
    },
  });
  Promise.all(
    [countPromise, countPromise2].map((e) => e.catch((error) => console.log(e)))
  ).then((values) => {
    if (values[0].count !== values[1].count)
      return res
        .status(400)
        .send(
          "can't change state to completedd when all subtaks are not compleed  "
        );
  });
};

module.exports = {
  isStatusChangeCorrect,
};
```

Comment: `await isStatusChangeCorrect` is inside `.then((todo) => {`, which is not marked as `async`. I suggest that you use `async`/`await` on `Todo.findByPk` so you don't end up with nested function calls (either use `.then()` or `await`, try not to mix both)

Answer (score 1):

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
   //find the todo needed to be updated
   return Todo.findByPk(req.params.todoId)
     .then(async (todo) => { // add async right here
        if (!todo) {
          return res.status(404).send({
          message: "Todo Not Found",
        });
     }
     const  answerr = await isStatusChangeCorrect(todo.status, req.body.status, 
  req.params.todoId);

  console.log("aaa2", subtaskMarkedCompleted);
  console.log("aaa", totalSubtasks);
  return todo
    .update({
      status: req.body.status || todo.status,
    })
    .then(() => res.status(200).send(todo))
    .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
   })
    .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
 };
```